# Why does neo4j checkpointing time increase with graph size?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a dataset of roughly 100GB split into 50 files which I want to import into an empty neo4j-3.5.5-enterprise with 16 GB heap and 8 GB page cache on a 32 GB RAM AWS server. The data is in JSON lines format and fed via python into this query:

```
WITH {list} as list
UNWIND list as data
MERGE (p:LabelA {id: data.id})
    SET p.prop1 = data.prop1, p.prop2 = data.prop2, p.prop3 = data.prop3, p.prop4 = data.prop4,
        p.prop5 = data.prop5, p.prop6 = data.prop6, p.prop7 = data.prop7, p.prop8 = data.prop8

MERGE (j:LabelF {name: data.prop9})
MERGE (p) -[:RELATION_A {prop1: data.prop10, prop2: data.prop11}]-> (j)

MERGE (v:LabelC {name: data.prop12})
MERGE (p) -[:RELATION_B]-> (v)

FOREACH (elem IN data.prop13 |
    MERGE (a:LabelB {id: elem.id}) ON CREATE
        SET a.name = elem.name
    MERGE (a) -[:RELATION_C]-> (p)
)

FOREACH (elem IN data.prop14 |
    MERGE (u:LabelF {name: elem.name})
    MERGE (u) -[:RELATION_C]-> (p)
)

FOREACH (elem IN data.prop15 |
    MERGE (e:LabelD {name: elem})
    MERGE (p) -[:RELATION_D]-> (e)
)

FOREACH (elem IN data.prop16 |
    MERGE (out:LabelA {id: elem})
    MERGE (p) -[:RELATION_E]-> (out)
)

FOREACH (elem IN data.prop17 |
    MERGE (inc:LabelA {id: elem})
    MERGE (p) <-[:RELATION_E]- (inc)
)

FOREACH (elem IN data.prop18 |
    MERGE (pdf:LabelG {name: elem})
    MERGE (p) -[:RELATION_F]-> (pdf)
)

FOREACH (elem IN data.prop19 |
    MERGE (s:LabelE {name: elem})
    MERGE (p) -[:RELATION_G]-> (s)
)
```

`list` contains 200 JSON lines and each query runs in its own transaction.

Indexes are set prior to data import:

```
self.graph.run('CREATE INDEX ON :LabelB(name)')
self.graph.run('CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:LabelA) ASSERT (p.id) IS NODE KEY;')
self.graph.run('CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:LabelB) ASSERT (p.id) IS NODE KEY;')
for label in ['LabelC', 'LabelD', 'LabelE', 'LabelF', 'LabelG', 'LabelF']:
    self.graph.run(f'CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:{label}) ASSERT (p.name) IS NODE KEY;')
```

The first couple of checkpoints are still somewhat fast (?):

```
2019-05-23 15:49:10.141+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 45 checkpoint completed in 134ms
2019-05-23 16:04:45.515+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 1603 checkpoint completed in 35s 345ms
2019-05-23 16:22:38.299+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 3253 checkpoint completed in 2m 52s 483ms
```

But at some point they stick to durations of about 20-25 minutes per checkpoint (this is from a previous attempt):

```
2019-05-23 07:40:03.755 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 18240 checkpoint started...
2019-05-23 07:42:15.942 INFO [o.n.k.NeoStoreDataSource] Rotated to transaction log [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.transaction.db.144] version=144, last transaction in previous log=18253
2019-05-23 07:45:51.982 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=224, gcTime=240, gcCount=1}
2019-05-23 07:46:42.059 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.c.CountsTracker] Rotated counts store at transaction 18279 to [/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.a], from [/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.b].
2019-05-23 07:53:49.108 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=158, gcTime=157, gcCount=1}
2019-05-23 08:03:11.556 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 18240 checkpoint completed in 23m 7s 800ms 
2019-05-23 08:03:11.710 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] Pruned log versions 140-141, last checkpoint was made in version 143

2019-05-23 08:04:38.454 INFO [o.n.k.NeoStoreDataSource] Rotated to transaction log [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.transaction.db.145] version=145, last transaction in previous log=18377
2019-05-23 08:05:57.288 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=248, gcTime=253, gcCount=1}
2019-05-23 08:11:08.331 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=143, gcTime=224, gcCount=1}
2019-05-23 08:16:37.491 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=228, gcTime=237, gcCount=1}

2019-05-23 08:18:11.732 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 18471 checkpoint started...
2019-05-23 08:23:18.767 INFO [o.n.k.NeoStoreDataSource] Rotated to transaction log [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.transaction.db.146] version=146, last transaction in previous log=18496
2019-05-23 08:24:55.141 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.c.CountsTracker] Rotated counts store at transaction 18505 to [/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.b], from [/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.a].
2019-05-23 08:38:21.660 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=136, gcTime=195, gcCount=1}
2019-05-23 08:40:46.261 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 18471 checkpoint completed in 22m 34s 529ms
2019-05-23 08:40:46.281 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] Pruned log versions 142-143, last checkpoint was made in version 145
```

Can anyone tell me what's happening here? I tried tinkering with the transaction retention and log size properties (increasing/decreasing) to no avail and ran this on a 64GB AWS server with 24 GB heap and 24 GB page cache. In all scenarios the time it takes to complete a checkpoint is increasing. While it took the first two files less than two hours to complete I aborted the import process of the third file after 6 hours because it would do stuff for 15 minutes (default time between checkpoints) and then be stuck in a checkpoint for 25 minutes.

**Update 2019-05-24 17:35 UTC+2**

I attempted the first part of cybersam's solution by using `CREATE` for relationship creation where applicable (i.e. the relationship is only represented once in the 100GB) and threw out the creation of `RELATION_E` which I will perform at a later stage with preprocessed input files. This leads to the following import query:

```
WITH {list} as list
UNWIND list as data
MERGE (p:LabelA {id: data.id})
    SET p.prop1 = data.prop1, p.prop2 = data.prop2, p.prop3 = data.prop3, p.prop4 = data.prop4,
        p.prop5 = data.prop5, p.prop6 = data.prop6, p.prop7 = data.prop7, p.prop8 = data.prop8

MERGE (j:LabelF {name: data.prop9})
CREATE (p) -[:RELATION_A {prop1: data.prop10, prop2: data.prop11}]-> (j)

MERGE (v:LabelC {name: data.prop12})
CREATE (p) -[:RELATION_B]-> (v)

FOREACH (elem IN data.prop13 |
    MERGE (a:LabelB {id: elem.id}) ON CREATE
        SET a.name = elem.name
    CREATE (a) -[:RELATION_C]-> (p)
)

FOREACH (elem IN data.prop14 |
    MERGE (u:LabelF {name: elem.name})
    CREATE (u) -[:RELATION_C]-> (p)
)

FOREACH (elem IN data.prop15 |
    MERGE (e:LabelD {name: elem})
    CREATE (p) -[:RELATION_D]-> (e)
)

FOREACH (elem IN data.prop18 |
    MERGE (pdf:LabelG {name: elem})
    CREATE (p) -[:RELATION_F]-> (pdf)
)

FOREACH (elem IN data.prop19 |
    MERGE (s:LabelE {name: elem})
    CREATE (p) -[:RELATION_G]-> (s)
)
```

Then I stopped my Neo4j, deleted the graph.db directory, changed the config to perform checkpoints every 15 sec so I can quickly tell if the checkpointing time still increases and started the data import. Unfortunately the time still increases:

```
2019-05-24 15:25:40.718+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 59 checkpoint completed in 240ms
2019-05-24 15:26:02.003+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 86 checkpoint completed in 1s 283ms
2019-05-24 15:26:27.518+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 105 checkpoint completed in 5s 514ms
2019-05-24 15:26:55.079+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 141 checkpoint completed in 7s 559ms
2019-05-24 15:27:23.944+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 179 checkpoint completed in 8s 864ms
2019-05-24 15:27:59.768+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 218 checkpoint completed in 15s 823ms
2019-05-24 15:28:42.819+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 269 checkpoint completed in 23s 9ms
2019-05-24 15:29:33.318+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 328 checkpoint completed in 30s 498ms
2019-05-24 15:30:32.847+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 397 checkpoint completed in 39s 489ms
2019-05-24 15:31:41.918+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 480 checkpoint completed in 49s 30ms
2019-05-24 15:33:03.113+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by scheduler for time threshold @ txId: 576 checkpoint completed in 1m 1s 194ms
```

Is there an index missing somewhere?

**Update 2019-05-28 18:44 UTC+2**

I created a parameter set of 100 lines and imported them using `PROFILE` into an empty Neo4j. The query plan looks like this:

[image: query execution plan]

**Update 2019-07-14 16:11 UTC+2**

I circumvented the problem by preprocessing my JSONL files into CSV files without duplicates and using `neo4j-admin import`.

Answer (score 2):

The cost of each `MERGE` operation for a relationship will increase linearly with the number of relationships that must be scanned. Node indexing will help to optimize finding a relationship's *endpoints*, but neo4j still has to scan the relationships of one of those endpoints in order for `MERGE` to know if the desired relationship already exists.

So, your query's execution time will grow as the number of relationships possessed by the individual nodes needed as relationship endpoints increases (which I surmise is happening in your case as you repeatedly execute your query).

Here is a 2-step process for fixing this.

1. Use a query that just uses `MERGE` to create the nodes (without any relationships). You can continue to use `MERGE` in this case, since you are just dealing with indexed nodes. For example:

   ```
   UNWIND $list as data
   MERGE (p:LabelA {id: data.id})
   ON CREATE SET
     p.prop1 = data.prop1, p.prop2 = data.prop2, p.prop3 = data.prop3, p.prop4 = data.prop4,
     p.prop5 = data.prop5, p.prop6 = data.prop6, p.prop7 = data.prop7, p.prop8 = data.prop8

   MERGE (j:LabelF {name: data.name})    
   MERGE (v:LabelC {name: data.propA})

   FOREACH (e IN data.propB |
     MERGE (a:LabelB {id: e.id}) ON CREATE SET a.name = e.name)
   FOREACH (e IN data.propC |
     MERGE (:LabelF {name: e.name}))
   FOREACH (e IN data.propD + data.propG + data.propH |
     MERGE (:LabelD {name: e}))
   FOREACH (e IN data.propE + data.propF |
     MERGE (:LabelA {id: e}))
   ```
2. Use a query that will process each relationship *just once*, allowing you to use `CREATE` (which does not need to scan) instead of `MERGE`.

   **NOTE: This second step requires that no 2 `$list` parameters (as used in separate query invocations) contain data that would cause the creation of the same relationship. And the same constraint exists within a single `$list` parameter as well. Generating such `$list` parameters is an exercise left up to you.**

   Once you have appropriate `$list` parameters, you can do this:

   ```
   UNWIND $list as data
   MATCH (p:LabelA {id: data.id})

   MATCH (j:LabelF {name: data.name})
   CREATE (p) -[:RELATION_A {prop1: data.prop1, prop2: data.prop2}]-> (j) 

   WITH p, data

   MATCH (v:LabelC) WHERE v.name IN data.propA
   CREATE (p) -[:RELATION_B]-> (v) 

   WITH p, data

   UNWIND data.propB as elem
   MATCH (a:LabelB {id: elem.id})
   CREATE (a) -[:RELATION_C]-> (p)   

   WITH p, data

   UNWIND data.propC as elem
   MATCH (u:LabelF) WHERE u.name IN elem.name
   CREATE (u) -[:RELATION_C]-> (p)

   WITH p, data

   MATCH (e:LabelD) WHERE e.name IN data.propD
   CREATE (p) -[:RELATION_D]-> (e) 

   WITH p, data

   MATCH (out:LabelA) WHERE out.id IN data.propE
   CREATE (p) -[:RELATION_E]-> (out)

   WITH p, data

   MATCH (inc:LabelA) WHERE inc.id IN data.propF
   CREATE (p) <-[:RELATION_E]- (inc)

   WITH p, data

   MATCH (pdf:G) WHERE pdf.name IN data.propG
   CREATE (p) -[:RELATION_F]-> (pdf)

   WITH p, data

   MATCH (s:LabelE) WHERE s.name IN data.propH
   CREATE (p) -[:RELATION_G]-> (s)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for that detailed response. I tried the first part without success and added the details of my attempt in the question. If you could have a look I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Can you add the [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) of your query to your question?

Comment: Also, can you confirm that your checkpoint times are calculated as (queryEndTIme - queryStartTime)? (I am making up some variable names here). In other words, is queryStartTime always determined by the actual query start time?

Comment: Please find the PROFILE attached to the question as most recent edit. Regarding checkpoint times... I have no idea what you're asking. I'm not calculating them myself but extracting them from the debug.log using `grep`. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Are the checkpoint times all calculated using the same exact start time? That would be one explanation for why your times are always increasing.

Comment: Ah, now I get you. No, that can't be the case as the log statements of the debug log show the timestamps of the `checkpoint started` and `checkpoint completed` log statements. The time difference of the log statements match the calculated time it takes for the checkpoint to be completed.